# User input to search engine

Tags: c#, html, xamarin, mobile, html-agility-pack

Is there a way you can go to a search engine and look something up using C#.?

For example, from my command prompt I type in Computer Science, and then it would either open up my browser and type in what I told it OR better yet, it could return the HTML.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
       intent.button.Click += delegate {
       var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("http://www.xamarin.com");
       var intent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, uri);
       StartActivity (intent); };
```

Comment: Note: this is for opening a website in a browser... it does not return html to the programmer.